# How to use environment variables to work in both React & Node.js app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, sdk, environment-variables

I'm working on a monorepo Typescript SDK. I have a function in one of its packages that expects the user to set their `api_key` & `secret` as environment variables. I read that from the `process.env.api_key` & pass onto a 3rd party SDK function which requires these credentials for authorization. This is how I implement it:

```
  //   @ts-ignore
  if (!process.env.API_KEY || !process.env.SECRET) {
    throw new Error('Please provide your API_KEY and SECRET as env variables');
  }

  //   @ts-ignore
  const authorization = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(process.env.API_KEY + ':' + process.env.SECRET).toString('base64');
  const res = thirdPartySDK.function({
    url,
    headers:{
      authorization
    }
  });
```

This works flawlessly in my test Node.js app when I set the required env vars. But I tried using this in a React app where it threw the **error** that the env vars are required to be set. The reason is that React expects its env vars to be prefixed with `REACT_APP` but my implementation above expects the env vars without that prefix.

**My question:** How can I read the env vars in an "app independent" manner? Since different apps may have different env vars format. Example React, Vite, etc. Ideally I should have to read only **1** env vars format. How should I go about this?

**My thoughts:**

1. Make the user responsible for ensuring to set the env vars in the above format i.e without the prefix. I tried for React & it seems quite cumbersome. I'm not sure whether it's even possible to use env vars in a React project without the `REACT_APP` prefix.
2. Ditch reading the env vars altogether & let the user **pass** the secrets to my function. I'm not a fan on this approach & the user has to trust our SDK with their secret.
3. Support both React & Node.js env vars separately. But then I have to do it for Vite, etc. That's why I'm looking for a single env vars format without the prefix.

Comment: why would a secret key be exposed to a frontend? Also, "the user has to trust our SDK with their secret" they already have to trust your SDK since you're grabbing their environment variables, making the user pass them in makes it explicit to the user what values you're using which is what most third party integrations do (make you pass in credentials).